# Opening .int files in ubuntu

Tags: text-editor, editor

I recently moved to ubuntu 14.04.1 from windows 8.1.  I am part of a translating crew, and ı translate a game now i have the files as .int at windows ı was using notepad++ in ubuntu ı tried some programs as kate but when i open files i see some rubbish symbols.  How can ı properly open and edit those files?

Comment: did you try gedit?

Comment: "some rubbish symbols" what kind? If possible upload an image and post the URL to it and someone will edit it into the question. Your problem is probably an encoding problem. Use `file {filename}` from command line to inspect the encoding of the file

Comment: Well gedit was not working but i tried again now it shows perfect but other programs still showing it like this in the link http://imgur.com/AtWh6Y6 i think gedit will be fine for me thank you for your helps

Comment: Provide it as an answer please and accept it when this becomes possible.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with gedit thanks for help